# Groovy: extend `setProperty` via extension module

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I've got a java class (tree structure in fact) and I want to access nodes of this class as properties like it is done in Groovy map. There is a [good explanation](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2010/01/groovy-goodness-override-getproperty.html) how to do so by manipulating `metaClass` property, but it requires to load this code before any other actions are done. The idea is to apply extension statically.

I tried to do so by implementing `getProperty` and `setProperty` via extension module, but runtime just ignores these methods or at least does not call them on property access. I know the behavior I want is somehow implemented for map, but is it possible to do so for custom object without a lot of headache?

Comment: Is a direct call to .getProperty(...) possible? I never worked with extension modules and might be wrong, but I think in order to use a java class in a groovy way, it still has to extend/implement GroovyObjectSupport.

Comment: Do you want to use thru `metaClass`? Do you have a sample class and what do you want to add to that class?

Comment: I'got a method in my java class that takes `String` as a parameter and returns a object of fixed type as a result. Also there is a two-argument setter. All I want is that method to be called on bean get/set operations. I do not have any objections to `metaClass` all I want is that it to be modified statically when program starts.

Comment: if you want to init it statically - do it.what is the problem?

Comment: If I place it into the class `static` block, it requires the class to be loaded by class loader first, so it won't work out of the box. Also standard solution from mrhaki won't work if I add `@CompileStatic` annotation.

Comment: I think I'm not the only one struggling to understand what's your problem. You apparently want to modify a map like java-class of which you don't have any control of. You want to add dynamic getter and setter methods to it, but also like to use @CompileStatic, which require the methods available at compile time. If you don't explain your use-case and post some code, I don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: I am not fixed on using `@CompileStatic` I just want the extension to be loaded automatically without ensuring that the class holding it is loaded. Otherwise I will need to call some initialization code each time I start the program.